# How to check if value exists and print it in the same order as in array?

Tags: php, arrays, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to make a sortable list with jQuery UI. On the backend everything seems to be working fine. The array is sending properly but I have some problems with displaying the correct list order at the frontend.

---

Here is how my array looks like. **print_r($results)**:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
         (
            [0] => "B"
            [1] => "A"
            [3] => "E"
         )
)
```

I am checking if specific values exist in an array:

```
<?php 
$letters = $myarray;
preg_match_all('/".*?"/', $letters, $results);
    if(in_array("A", $results, true)) { ?> 
      <span><i class="icon"></i>Letter A exists</span>
<?php  } 
    if(in_array("B", $results, true)) { ?> 
      <span><i class="icon"></i>Letter B exists</span>
<?php  }  
    if(in_array("C", $results, true)) { ?> 
      <span><i class="icon"></i>Letter C exists</span>
<?php  }  
    if(in_array("D", $results, true)) { ?> 
      <span><i class="icon"></i>Letter D exists</span>
<?php  }  
    if(in_array("E", $results, true)) { ?> 
      <span><i class="icon"></i>Letter E exists</span>
<?php  } ?>   
...
```

After that I want to display results in the same order as in array:

```
<span><i class="icon"></i>Letter B exists</span>
<span><i class="icon"></i>Letter A exists</span>
<span><i class="icon"></i>Letter E exists</span>
```

---

How can I do this in a proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply loop through `$results`:

```
foreach ($results[0] as $letter){
    printf('<span><i class="icon"></i>Letter %s exists</span>', $letter);
}
```

This will output your html nodes in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use array_intersect() function from PHP. To do so you will have to make an array of your letters and then check $results against that new array. Here is an example :

```
<?php 
$results = [['B', 'A', 'E']];
$matches = array_intersect($results[0], ['A','B','C','D','E']);
foreach($matches as $match){
    echo "<span><i class='icon'></i>Letter $match exists</span><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below, modified your code and it is giving result.

```
<?php
$myarray = array("0" => array("0" => "B","1" => "A","3" => "E"));
print_r($myarray[0]);

$letters = $myarray[0];

if(in_array("A", $letters, true)) { 
    echo '<span><i class="icon"></i>Letter A exists</span>';
} 
?>
```